# Mysteriously disappearing individual array elements that are still somehow in there and usable in the full array expansion

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, zsh

The following problem (or misunderstanding from my part)
arises in the same way in both *bash* and *zsh*.

I wrote the examples using *zsh*, so the array indices I use are shifted by 1
with respect to *bash* (*bash* arrays start at 0, whereas *zsh* arrays start at 1).

So, I'm defining an array like that:

```
fileFilter=(
  grep -v
  -e '/filesToCache\.json$'
  -e '/CNAME$'
  -e '/style\.js.*$'
  -e '/worker\..*$'
)
```

If I do `echo "${fileFilter[@]}"` I get:

> grep -v -e /filesToCache.json$ -e /CNAME$ -e /style.js.*$ -e /worker..*$

which is totally what I expect.

What baffles me is that I cannot seem to access some elements individually by index.

`echo "${fileFilter[1]}"` yields `grep` as expected,

`echo "${fileFilter[2]}"` yields `-v` as expected

**But `echo "${fileFilter[3]}"` doesn't print *anything*** even though `echo "${fileFilter[4]}"` (i.e. the element after the invisible one) prints the expected `/filesToCache\.json$`.

It seems like array index 3 (and same for all indices corresponding to a `-e`) is somehow
in-addressable, but the element is not lost, as it appears in the full expansion of `fileFilter` in expressions, I can see it with `echo "${fileFilter[@]}"`, or when embedding the array in a command such as `find docs -type f | "${fileFilter[@]}"`.

I do not understand this behaviour.

Comment: See also [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819) on [unix.se].

Comment: hmmmm ... creating the array in my environment: `echo "${fileFilter[3]}"` => `/filesToCache\.json$.`; `typeset -p fileFilter` => ` typeset -p fileFilter` => `declare -a fileFilter=([0]="grep" [1]="-v" [2]="-e" [3]="/filesToCache\\.json\$" [4]="-e" [5]="/CNAME\$" [6]="-e" [7]="/style\\.js.*\$" [8]="-e" [9]="/worker\\..*\$")`; might be interesting to update the question with the results of running `typeset -p fileFilter` in your environment

Comment: @djfm : You mention bash and zsh, but with arrays they differ considerably. For instance, index [1] denotes the second array element in bash, but the first in zsh. Please clarify what you **expect** in **which** shell and what you actually get.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that `echo '-e'` seems to have some meaning to `echo` and prints nothing.

This was not an issue with the arrays.

Comment: This is why `printf` is recommended over `echo`. `echo -e` in `bash` enables the POSIX-specified behavior of expanding certain escape sequences in the arguments. `echo "\t"` output the digraph `\t`, while `echo -e "\t"` outputs a literal tab character.

Comment: ...just to be a little more clear about chepner's comment above -- expanding escape sequences is __always on__ for a version of `echo` that follows the POSIX spec with XSI extensions. To have that behavior be off and then turn it on only when `-e` is seen _actually violates the standard_, in which `-n` is the only permissible flag (note "flag", not "argument") that can cause implementation-defined changes in output.

Comment: (though using a backslash anywhere in `echo`'s arguments makes `echo`'s output no longer specified or guaranteed by the baseline, non-XSI-extended POSIX sh standard in the first place)

Comment: I'm more and more surprised of seeing echo used all over the place given all of its strange behaviors I'm learning about! Add that to bash, which, in itself, is already quite a mysterious thing, and you get something that truly resembles black magic